# Supabase Sum Amount specific field

Tags: javascript, supabase, nuxtjs3

My supabase query with nuxt3:

```
const client = useSupabaseClient()
const { data: expenses } = await useAsyncData('count', async () => {
  const { data, count } = await client.from<Expenses>('expenses').select('amount, currency', { count: 'exact' })
  return { data, count }
})
console.log('useAsyncData :', expenses.value)
```

This is my result:

[image]

**I want to sum of amount and group by currency**

***Result I want:***

> const result = { 0: 33800, 1: 10 }

Comment: You should probably give [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) a try.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `transform` property of `useAsyncData` to manipulate the result of the operation. The code (surely could be improved):

```js
    const { data: expenses } = await useAsyncData("count", async () => {
        const { data } = await ...
        return data;
    }, {
        transform: (data) => {
            const result = {};

            const groups = data.reduce((acc, d) => {
                const found = acc.find((a) => a.currency === d.currency);
                const value = { amount: d.amount };
                if (!found) {
                    acc.push({ currency: d.currency, data: [value] });
                } else {
                    found.data.push(value);
                }
                return acc;
            }, []);

            groups.forEach((group) => {
                result[group.currency] = group.data.map(i => i.amount).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
            });

            return result;
        }
    });
```

Will return

```json
{
  "0": 33800,
  "1": 10
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answer It's the best resolved